# Doc2Vec not providing adequate results in most_similar

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I'm trying to use Doc2Vec to go through the classic exercise of training on Wikipedia articles, using the article title as the tag.

Here's my code and the results, is there something that I'm missing that they would not give the matching results with most_similar? Following [this tutorial](https://markroxor.github.io/gensim/static/notebooks/doc2vec-wikipedia.html), but I used the wiki-english-20171001 dataset that came with gensim.

```
import gensim.downloader as api
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
import re

def cleanText(text):
    text = re.sub(r'\|\|\|', r' ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'http\S+', r'<URL>', text)
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',text)
    return text


wiki = api.load("wiki-english-20171001")

data = [d for d in wiki]

for i in range(10):
    print(data[i])
def my_create_tagged_docs(data):
    for wikiidx in range(len(data)):
        yield TaggedDocument([i for i in data[wikiidx].get('section_texts') for i in cleanText(i).split()], [data[wikiidx].get('title')])


wiki_data = my_create_tagged_docs(data)
del data
del wiki


model = Doc2Vec(dm=1, dm_mean=1, size=200, window=8, min_count=19, iter =10, epochs=40)
model.build_vocab(wiki_data)

model.train(wiki_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
```

```
model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=["Lady Gaga"], topn=10)
```

```
[('Chlorothrix', 0.35521823167800903),
 ("A Child's Garden of Verses", 0.3533579707145691),
 ('Fish Mooney', 0.35129639506340027),
 ('2000 Paris–Roubaix', 0.3463437855243683),
 ('Calvin C. Chaffee', 0.3439667224884033),
 ('Murders of Eve Stratford and Lynne Weedon', 0.3397218585014343),
 ('Black Air', 0.3396576941013336),
 ('Turzyn', 0.3312540054321289),
 ('Scott Baker', 0.33018186688423157),
 ('Amongst the Waves', 0.3297169804573059)]
```

```
model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=["Machine learning"], topn=10)
```

```
[('Wolf Rock, Connecticut', 0.3855834901332855),
 ('Amália Rodrigues', 0.3349645137786865),
 ('Victoria Park, Leicester', 0.33312514424324036),
 ('List of visual anthropology films', 0.3311382532119751),
 ('Sadqay Teri Mout Tun', 0.3287636637687683),
 ('T. Damodaran', 0.32876330614089966),
 ('Urqu Jawira (Aroma)', 0.32281631231307983),
 ('Tiggy Wiggy', 0.3226730227470398),
 ('Frédéric Brun (cyclist, born 1988)', 0.32106447219848633),
 ('Unholy Crusade', 0.3200794756412506)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `wiki_data` is a single-pass generator, as returned by `my_create_tagged_docs()`, which can be iterated over only once - not an iterable object capable of many iterations, as the many steps of the `Doc2Vec` training requires.

You can test your `wiki_data` object for whether it's multiply-iterable, just after it's been assigned, by executing:

```py
    print(sum(1 for _ in wiki_data))
    print(sum(1 for _ in wiki_data))
```

If you see the same number twice – the total number of documents – all's well. If the 2nd number is `0`, you've created a single-use iterator instead of a multiple-use *iterable*.

As a result, the `build_vocab()` call will work to initialize the known-vocabulary & model – but then the `train()` will see an empty iterable, completing instantly with no real training happening. (If you run with logging at the INFO level, this may be obvious in the log timestamps for the various steps.)

Two possible fixes:

If you're lucky enough to have enough RAM to hold the whole corpus as Python objects, converting it into a in-memory list would ensure it's multiple-iterable:

```py
    wiki_data = list(my_create_tagged_docs(data))
```

But, most won't have that much RAM * shouldn't/needn't take that step. Instead, you can define a class for an iterable view on the data, which can return a fresh iterator every time it's needed. There's an example with further explanation in a blog post by the founder of the `gensim` project at:

https://rare-technologies.com/data-streaming-in-python-generators-iterators-iterables/